# Idiomatic translation of Django models to different API schemas, perhaps with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-requests

**Whats the best/idiomatic way to create and pass data between different API schemas/formats in Django or with Django Rest Framework?** I'm imagining something like a translation serializer that hooks between APIs that could be reused anywhere or in nested format, and wanted to see what the best practices are.

Say I have a standard Django Rest Framework based API and model that I expose via DRF that looks something like this : (But has alot more complexity and nested relationships

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)

class PersonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

Response looks something like this

```
{
    "first_name": "Oliver",
    "middle_name": null,
    "last_name": "Zhou",
    "company": {
        "name": "Company ABC",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/companies/1234/"
    }
}
```

**Now, depending on different actions in the application, I have a different API I need to integrate with and pass the Person data to, for example, an API with a schema with something like this :**

```
{
    "first_name": "Oliver",
    "middle_name": null,
    "last_name": "Zhou",
    "company": {
         "name": "Company ABC"
    }
}
```

What I've been doing is ugly and a spaghetti network of 'if' 'else' and nested logic trying to wrangle data into the proper format in a way that isn't reusable like a Serializer for each Django Model is for creation of standard Django Rest Framework ViewSets

```
def post_person(person)
    data = {}
    try:
         data['first_name'] = person.first_name
         data['last_name'] = person.last_name
         if person.company:
             data['company']['name'] = person.company.name
    except AttributeError as e:
        logger.info("AttributeError {}".format(e))

    # pseudocode here, but eventually after finishing the nesting 
    # we post a response with the 'requests' library
    # response = requests.request(
    #    method, url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a perfect solution to this problem but these are some of the things I did in the past to mitigate the pain:

- Heavily lean toward the direction of including a superset of the data/fields possibly needed. In most programming context it's harmless to have extra fields (`company.url` in your case). The obvious drawback of this approach is to have very bloated response body with most of the data just being thrown away at the client side.
- Have a hierarchy of `Serializer` classes that represent data at different detail level. For your case it can be `SkeletonPersonSerializer` <- `BasicPersonSerializer` <- `DetailedPersonSerializer` <- `FullPersonSerializer`, each class inheriting from the one before it and adds some more fields. But I have to admit that in reality this approach will get out of control pretty soon, especially when you have a network of related objects that need to be pulled in at different times.

The promise of GraphQL is to solve exactly this problem. I just got involved in a real-world, complex project that uses GraphQL. Will update this answer once I form some opinions on whether or not the real benefit of GraphQL deserves its hype.